# Detecting misuse of lambdas with static analysis in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, optimization, resharper

A coworker of mine started with this code:

```
var newList = new List<>();

foreach(var item in otherList)
{
    newList.Add(GetNewObjectFrom(item));
}
```

ReSharper correctly identified a use of LINQ here, and changed it to:

```
var newList = otherList.Select(o => GetNewObjectFrom(o)).ToList();
```

However, the lambda is unnecessary, and could be simplified further by just passing the method:

```
var newList = otherList.Select(GetNewObjectFrom).ToList();
```

**My question**:

Can any tool within Visual Studio 2010 Professional, or various arm-twisting of ReSharper, detect this change that should be made?  I realize that the best tool is a second set of human eyes, and that's where this question comes from to begin with ... but the more of my job that's done by computers, the better.

edit: awesome, it's a ReSharper bug.  Here's a sample program:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace ResharperMethodGroupBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new NumberProgram(new NumberProcessor());
            program.Run();
        }
    }

    class NumberProgram
    {
        private readonly INumberProcessor numberProcessor;

        public NumberProgram(INumberProcessor numberProcessor)
        {
            this.numberProcessor = numberProcessor;
        }

        static long SquareNumber(int n)
        {
            return n * n;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var listOfNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

            // appropriately triggers "convert to method group"
            var listOfSquares = listOfNumbers.Select(n => SquareNumber(n));

            // does not trigger "convert to method group" when it should
            var listOfCubes = listOfNumbers.Select(n => this.numberProcessor.CubeNumber(n));

            // proof that a method group works here
            var anotherListOfCubes = listOfNumbers.Select(this.numberProcessor.CubeNumber);
        }
    }

    interface INumberProcessor
    {
        long CubeNumber(int n);
    }

    class NumberProcessor : INumberProcessor
    {
        public long CubeNumber(int n)
        {
            return n * n * n;
        }
    }
}
```

edit 2:  I've posted an issue on JetBrains' Youtrack:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-301259

Comment: Resharper already detects this and suggests the simplification.

Comment: nuh-uh (15 chars)   (also trying R# 7.0 build to see if that one does)

Comment: I checked before I posted my comments, and I can assure you it does detect it (VS2010 Pro SP1, Resharper 5.1.3)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: please post that as an answer so I can accept it once I figure out what's gone wrong.

Comment: did you report the bug on the Jetbrains tracker? Please post the link so that other people can vote on it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper already detects this and suggest the simplification:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var list = items.Select(i => Foo(i)).ToList(); // R# suggests "Convert to method group"
    }

    static int Foo(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
```

(tested with VS2010 Pro SP1 and R# 5.1.3)

Comment: Seems it will detect this when the method is local, but not if the method is presented as an interface member.  Off to file a bug report with R#.

Comment: would you mind using the sample program I posted above and see if your version of R# detects the method group?

Comment: @insta, just tried, it gives the same result in R# 5.1.3. I agree this is a bug.